# AWS Lambda: Can't execute POST request to another Lambda from within one

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

Having an odd issue and hoping someone can try to help out!

I have two lambdas. One lambda's entire job is to send some extra data to the other one **and not wait for a response** in order to trigger the other lambda to do its thing.

I've tried several methods of sending a request, but can't seem to break past the barrier of the first lambda just refusing to actually execute the call.

When I go to monitor both lambdas in CloudWatch, I can see the first one get called with no errors, but the second one never gets pinged.

Here's how i'm currently calling the other lambda;

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();
import * as http from 'http';

export const handler = async (event) => {
    console.log(process.version);

    const jsonData = JSON.parse(event.body);
    console.log(jsonData);
    const recordID = jsonData.record_id;

    try {
        fetch('https://lambda2.lambda-url.us-east-1.on.aws/', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({ record_id: `${recordID}` }),
            headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' },
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log('Okay?');
        });

        const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: {
                message: 'SENT TO SERVER',
            },
        };
        return response;
    } catch (errorMsg) {
        console.log(errorMsg);
        const response = {
            statusCode: 400,
            body: {
                error: errorMsg,
            },
        };
        return response;
    }
};
```

To try to fix this, i've tried the following Node based libraries:

Axios
HTTP
Req
Fetch

All four refuse to actually call that other API.

I'm guessing i'm missing something stupidly simple & Hoping someone can help out! Thank you!

Comment: You should `invoke` the other lambda: https://www.sqlshack.com/calling-an-aws-lambda-function-from-another-lambda-function/